# How to add HTML and JS functionality to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So there is an external service whose only way of accessing their sdk is exampled via a monolithic static website, however I am working with a React app.

I have found that if I use the component in this manner:

```
import React from 'react';

const acmeID = `<h1>Howdy!</h1>`;

export default function AcmeID() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: acmeID}} />;
}
```

I can get this component to render to the screen without having to go into `App.js` and remove it as a `<Route />` and without having to use HTML anchor tags, but I need to utilize a script tag with a JavaScript source to access the sdk. Could I build out a whole HTML markup including that javascript script tag inside that `acmeID` variable? I just tried putting together an HTML boilerplate markup in there and I got a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think because react makes an production for these nestings